# MobX React Native throws cannot read property of undefined

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-persist

I'm trying to pass one mobX store to another store, following are my store codes:

Store class 1:

```
export default class APIKeyStore
{
    @persist @observable apiKey = '****';
}
```

Store Class 2:

```
export default class ServiceCalls
{
    @persist @observable apiKeysStore;

    constructor(apiStore)
    {
        this.apiKeysStore = apiStore; 
        console.log('constructor', this.apiKeysStore.apiKey);
    }

    @action async initializeApp()
    {
        console.log('initializeApp', this.apiKeyStore.apiKey);
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
import APIKeyStore from './models/APIKeyStore';
import ServiceCalls from './models/ServiceCalls';

const serviceCalls = new ServiceCalls(new APIKeyStore())

const stores = {
  serviceCalls: serviceCalls
}

export default
{
  ...stores
};
```

Component file where I'm calling store 2's initializeApp() method:

```
@inject('serviceCalls')
@observer
class ZeroStepScreen extends Component
{
  async componentWillMount()
  {
    try
    {
      console.log('componentWillMount', this.props.serviceCalls.apiKeysStore.apiKey);
      await this.props.serviceCalls.initializeApp();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

In above classes, I have three `console.log(..)` declarations - where it reports proper results from the 2nd store's `constructor`, and the component's `componentWillMount()` methods.

When calling the same 2nd store class' `initializeApp()` method, `this.apiKeysStore.apiKey` always throws me cannot read property of undefined.

2nd class' constructor - `console.log(this.apiKeysStore.apiKey)` - OK

ZeroStepScreen - `console.log(this.props.serviceCalls.apiKeysStore.apiKey)` - OK

2nd class' initializeApp() - `console.log(this.apiKeysStore.apiKey)` - Error

I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong that the 2nd store class getting undefined when accessing `this.apiKeysStore.apiKey` when its constructor reported right, the component class reported right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about the fundamentals (to do these ways' of things) but following way in an end worked for me:

```
@action async initializeApp()
{
   console.log(this.getAPIKeyStore()).apiKey);
}

getAPIKeyStore()
{
  return this.apiKeysStore;
}
```

Probably using `async` not able me to access the class level observer directly.